# Radio input in v-for loop selects multiple radio buttons of the same value

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

A bit difficult to explain,

I have created a simple rating system which uses `input type ="radio"` for a products array.

Using `v-for="product in products"`, I loop through the array showing all the products on the page.

```
            <div class="block" v-for="product in products">
                    <h3>{{product.name}}</h3>
                    <p>Desc: {{product.description}}</p>
                    <p>Price: £{{product.price}}</p>


                    <h3>Rating</h3>
                    <form @submit.prevent="ratingAdd(product)">
                    <input type="radio" value = "1" name = "ratings1" v-model="ratingNum">1
                    <input type="radio" value = "2" name = "ratings2" v-model="ratingNum">2
                    <input type="radio" value = "3" name = "ratings3" v-model="ratingNum">3
                    <input type="radio" value = "4" name = "ratings4" v-model="ratingNum">4
                    <input type="radio" value = "5" name = "ratings5" v-model="ratingNum">5
                    <input type="submit">

                </div>
```

The products display just fine, but whenever I click on a radio button it selects multiple radio buttons of the same value across all products. i.e If I click on 3 on product 1, it would select 3 on the rest of the products as well.

I did try using the same name as well. It does not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need unique names for radio buttons [input radio docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio).

You could use index in [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) to have unique names. Also your `v-model` need to be bind independently for each product.

```
<div class="block" v-for="(product, index) in products">
    <h3>{{product.name}}</h3>
    <p>Desc: {{product.description}}</p>
    <p>Price: £{{product.price}}</p>
    <h3>Rating</h3>
    <form @submit.prevent="ratingAdd(product, index)">
    <input type="radio" value = "1" :name = "'ratings1-' + index" v-model="ratingNum[index]">1
    <input type="radio" value = "2" :name = "'ratings2-' + index" v-model="ratingNum[index]">2
    <input type="radio" value = "3" :name = "'ratings2-' + index" v-model="ratingNum[index]">3
    <input type="radio" value = "4" :name = "'ratings4-' + index" v-model="ratingNum[index]">4
    <input type="radio" value = "5" :name = "'ratings5-' + index" v-model="ratingNum[index]">5
    <input type="submit">
</div>
```

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    ratingNum: [0, 0],
    loggedUser: {
      email: 'test@test'
    },
    products: [
      {
          name: 'Product A',
          description: 'desc A',
          price: 2,
      },
      {
        name: 'Product B',
        description: 'desc B',
        price: 3,
      }
    ]
  },
  methods:
  {
    ratingAdd: function(product, index) { 
      let newRating = { "name": product.name, "description": product.description, "price": product.price, "email": this.loggedUser.email, "rating": this.ratingNum[index] };
      console.log(newRating);
  }
}});
```

Example output:

```
{name: "Product A", description: "desc A", price: 2, email: "test@test", rating: "4"}
{name: "Product B", description: "desc B", price: 3, email: "test@test", rating: "3"}
```

Comment: I updated the answer - there was still no index at ratingNum. Now it should work.

Comment: I changed the :name = "'ratings' + index" for all the radio fields, but the ratingNum [0, 0] makes it so my ratingAdd(product) function no longer works, it returns undefined if I rate.

Comment: Also I changed the name as it wouldn't deselect if I changed value.

Comment: Please post code of your ratingAdd(product) method.

Comment: `ratingAdd(product) {
          const newRating = {
          "name": product.name,
          "description": product.description,
          "price": product.price,
          "email": this.loggedUser.email,
          "rating": this.ratingNum
    }`

Comment: Essentially this is a fetch post, it pushes the rating to the database. It pushes '0' to the database. Whereas before it did send the number.

Comment: I updated the answer - the expected output from ratingAdd(product, index) is logged in the console.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. This works. Appreciate the time.